# Tranfer excel sheet data to access table from excel vba giving error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to tranfer excel sheet data to access table. Below code throws an error **variable not defind** and pointing to **acImport** .  The TransferSpreadsheet method works from excel? Any alternate way is there to tranfer sheet data to access only from excel.

```
   Private Sub Cal_WEM_Click()
   Dim appAccess As Object
   Dim aPath, aDbase, aDSource, aTable, exePath As String
   Dim fileParam As String
   aPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
   aDbase = "Linear.accdb"
   aDSource = aPath & "\" & aDbase

  Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
  appAccess.Visible = True

  appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase aDSource

 appAccess.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet transfertype:=acImport, _
        tablename:="yorno", _
        FileName:=aPath, Hasfieldnames:=True, _
        Range:="WEM!D:E", SpreadsheetType:=5
        appAccess.DoCmd.OpenForm "Input_Form_WEM"

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
 Application.Quit
 Exit Sub
 End Sub
```

Comment: Where is acImport in this code?

Comment: Isn't it predefined. How to specify the same Tranferspreadsheet command in excel, because it works from access with same Docmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out by declaring the variables like this

```
 Const acImport = 0
 Const acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9 = 8

 appAccess.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
"wemonoff1", ename, True, "WEM-ONOFF!D:E"
```